# I get an error in Angular when I "npm install ngx-toastr --save"

Tags: angular, node-modules, npm-install, ngx-toastr

I wanted to install the ToastrService but I get an error when installing it.

[image]

does anybody know why that happens?
I saw, that it might be the angular version.
Does anybody know what i could do to resolve that issue?

thx in advance!

~ Max

Comment: As a side note, please don't use Powershell to run this kind of commands. It's well known that causes some bugs.

Comment: i am using the intellij terminal, but what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

As you are on angular 15, You should install `npm i ngx-toastr@16.2.0`. The latest version of toastr aka 17 version support angular 16.

I would recommend you to go through the README of third party package once before installing it.